# foreach loop only executing all code on the first iteration, selectively executing code on further iterations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just getting started with programing in unity and I can't figure out why this foreachloop is not working. For each element in the dictionary, I would like it to first print the name of the item, then print a message based on whether or not the player can afford the item. For some reason, it is printing the item name every iteration, but only printing the message the first iteration.

Here is my code:

```
void Start()
{  
    Dictionary<string, int> itemInventory = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        { "Potion", 5 },
        { "Antidote", 7 },
        { "Aspirin", 1 }
    };

    int playerGold = 12;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in itemInventory)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Item: {0} - {1}g", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        if (kvp.Value <= playerGold)
            Debug.LogFormat("You can afford this!");
        else
            Debug.LogFormat("Sorry, you're too broke to afford this!");
    }

}
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF6DO.png) is what it's printing to the console:

Item: Potion- 5g

You can afford this!

Item: Antidote- 7g

Item: Aspirin- 1g

So I'm just not sure why it's not printing the message each time!

Comment: @J... Incorrect, That semicolon is fine.

Comment: Coukd it be you have cascade mode in your console?

Comment: Like @Everts suggests, this is probably just your console hiding duplicate messages. Your code works just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BTghxv

Comment: I don't have a Unity setup, just plain old VS and Windows.  I copied your code, changing `Debug.LogFormat` to `Debug.WriteLine`.  It does what you'd expect it to.  Perhaps `Debug.LogFormat` does some caching and it won't write out duplicate `You can afford this!` strings (you never decrement player gold, so you can afford all of those things).  What happens if you initialize `playerGold` to `6`?

Comment: You can easily check if those lines are running by setting a breakpoint inside your if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not enough in your screenshot - just a hint of it - but I believe you have the "collapse" button turned on in your console window. This groups similar output so you don't get spammed by the same debug output over and over again.

EDIT: Trying to find a screenshot as I don't currently have Unity installed on this box I found a similar question with the same answer on Unity Answers.

[image]

Source: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1837643/debuglog-prints-only-sometimes.html